# Saving Texture2D in Dictionary and retrieve it afterwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am importing profile images from Parse.com into my unity project and inserting them into a Dictionary list with the specific users id as key and the image (Texture2D) as value like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> oppimageslinks = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public Dictionary<string, Texture2D> oppimages = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> image in oppimageslinks){

    var oppImageRequest = new WWW(image.Value);
    yield return oppImageRequest;
    oppimages.Add(image.Key,oppImageRequest.texture);

}
```

This part works just fine. Now, my issue is how to get the Texture2D into my gameObject afterwards? Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
if(oppimages.ContainsKey(game.Value[2])){
    UITexture picture = GameObject.Find("Game"+mc+"/Background/ProfileImg").GetComponent<UITexture>();
    picture.mainTexture = oppimages.Value;
}
```

game.Value[2] is the current opponents userid.

I get this error when trying to do this:

*Type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,UnityEngine.Texture2D>' does not contain a definition for`Value' and no extension method `Value' of type`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I am not sure how to solve this and are hoping for some help in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what happened. Maybe you could try this?

```
if(oppimages.ContainsKey(game.Value[2])){
UITexture picture = GameObject.Find("Game"+mc+"/Background/ProfileImg").GetComponent<UITexture>();
picture.mainTexture = oppimages[game.Value[2]];
}
```